# How does finite integral implies convergence almost everywhere in this proof in Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand a step in the following proof of completeness of $L^p$ in [Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf). (See the proof on page 5 of the link or at the end of this post.)

In the proof, it is said that:

> ... applying the monotone convergence theorem implies that $\int g^p<\infty$, and therefore, the series defining $g$ and hence the series defining $f$ converges almost everywhere, and $f\in L^p$.

I do not understand why.

**Question 1**: How does one get from the above argument that the almost everywhere convergence?

**Question 2**: How does one get that $f\in L^p$?

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's a theorem that convergence in $Lp$ implies a convergence almost everywhere of a sub-sequence. I suppose you can get rid of the sub-sequence somehow, though I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g \geq 0$ and $\int g^p<\infty$, $g^p$ (and thus $g$) is finite almost everywhere. Thus the series defining $g$ converges almost everywhere.

Since $|S_K(f)(x)| \leq S_K(g)(x)$ for all $x$, the series defining $f(x)$ converges for almost every $x$.

Finally, $|f| \leq |g|=g$, so $\int|f|^p \leq \int g^p < \infty$, so $f \in L^p$.

Comment: What is the result that guarantee the first line?

Comment: Well what happens to $\int g^p$ if $g \geq 0$ and $g^p$ is infinite on a set of positive measure?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know much about $L_p$ results.

Comment: This is nothing to do with $L_p$, just the definition of integration. If $g=\infty$ on a set $A$ of positive measure, what is $\int_A g^p $? Then, since $g \geq 0$, we have $ \int g^p  \geq \int_A g^p $...

Comment: I think your first paragraph is not necessary since we have that $S_K(g)$ converges. Hence $g=\vert g\vert$ converges which can be seen as $|g|<\infty$ thus $|g|^p<\infty$, thus $\int|g|^p<\infty$.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $|g|<\infty$ everywhere, only *almost* everywhere. This is a result of the fact that $\int g^p<\infty$. Moreover, your claim that $|g|<\infty$ implies $\int |g|^p<\infty$ is false.

Comment: almost everywhere, then there must be a set of measure zero such that $\vert g\vert$ is not finite, where is this set?

Comment: This set of measure zero could be $\emptyset$, but it could be nonempty. I can't possibly say what this set is when the functions $f_n$ are completely arbitrary, but the point is such a set could exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93566/discussion-between-galleta-and-kccu).

Comment: I think a proof for this is needed, finite almost everywhere then converges almost everywhere. Could you provide please?

Comment: If a series has a finite sum then it converges. That is what it means to converge, that is the definition.

Comment: yes:) but notice I wrote _almost everywhere_ .Anyway nevermind I am reading of it. (I should have delete my previous comment hehe..)

Comment: The "almost everywhere" doesn't change anything. That's just shortcut for "on a set whose complement has measure zero." If this series is finite at a point $x$, it converges at a point $x$ because this is the definition of convergence. Thus if it is finite almost everywhere (i.e., at every $x$ in a set whose complement has measure zero), then it converges almost everywhere (i.e., at every $x$ in a set whose complement has measure zero).