# Why is $\int g^p<\infty$ in this proof of completeness of $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am trying to understand a step in the proof of completeness of $L^p$ in [Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis](http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9627.pdf). (See the proof on page 5 of the link or at the end of this post.)

> In the first part of the proof, it is shown that
>   $$
> \int g^p<\infty.
> $$
>   **Question**: how is this done?

---

My thought was that as the partial sum $_()$ converges, the whole series $g=|g|$ converges which can be seen as $|g|<\infty$ thus $|g|^p<\infty$, and thus $\int|g|^p<\infty$. However, such argument will get into conflict with  "$g$ converges almost everywhere." which is in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3222553/9464) to another question of mine.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: My thought process is as follows

$||S_K(g)||_{L^p} < \infty$, hence this is true for any $K$, and $S_K(g) \to g$ (and indeed also $f$) in $L^p$ norm, so $||g||_{L^p}<\infty$ by taking limits. That gives you both $f$ and $g$ $\in L^p$

Comment: you should cite the resource (rudin?)

Comment: again, please cite the resource. I think it is inappropriate to post a picture from a textbook with zero credit given to the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proof, it is shown that
$$
\|S_K(g)\|_{L^p}\leq \|f_{n_1}\|_{L^p}+\sum_{k=1}^K2^{-k},
$$
which implies that (it is an instructive exercise to show that instead of $\limsup_{K\to\infty}$, one actually has $\lim_{K\to\infty}$ in (*))
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty} \|S_K(g)\|_{L^p} \leq \|f_{n_1}\|_{L^p}+1=:C\tag{*}
$$
for some positive real constant $C$.
By continuity of the function $h\mapsto h^{p}$ on $[0,\infty)$ and the definition of the $L^p$ norm, we have
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty}\int |S_K(g)|^p\leq C^p.\tag{1}
$$

(Remark: $S_K(g)$ is nonnegative for all $K$ and thus $|S_K(g)|=S_K(g)$.)

On the other hand, $S_K(g)\to g$ everywhere by the definitions of $S_K(g)$ and $g$. By the monotone convergence theorem, 
$$
\lim_{K\to\infty}\int[S_K(g)(x)]^p\,dx=\int\lim_{K\to\infty}[S_K(g)(x)]^p\,dx
=\int g(x)^p\,dx\tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2) together, we have
$$
\int g^p<\infty.
$$

Comment: Are you using the continuity of $h$ to guarantee this $(\lim_{K\to\infty}\int |S_K(g)|^p)^p=\lim_{K\to\infty}(\int |S_K(g)|^p)^p$ ?

Comment: :) For the instructive exercise I think you meant instead of $\lim_{K\to\infty }$ one has $\limsup_{K\to\infty}$ no?

Comment: Yes for the continuity of $h\mapsto h^p$. For the exercise, I mean in general, if one has $a_n\leq C$ for all $n$, then one has $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq C$; the limit  $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ does not necessarily exists. Whenever the limit exists, one has $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$. Here, one can show that $\lim_{K\to\infty}\|S_K(g)\|_{L^p}$ does exist and hence instead of $\limsup_{K\to\infty}$, one can use $\lim_{K\to\infty}$ in ($*$).

Comment: ah. I will keep in mind. And thank you for all the previous and current help

Comment: @galleta: You are welcome `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The integral is finite because we can take limits on either side of
$$
||S_K(g)||_p^p\leq (||f_{n_1}||+\sum_{k=1}^K 2^{-k})^p
$$
and using monotone convergence to move the limit inside the norm on the left hand side
$$
\lim_{K\to \infty}||S_K(g)||_p^p\leq (||f_{n_1}||+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k})^p=(||f_{n_1}||+1)^p\\
\stackrel{\text{monotone convergence}}\implies 
||\lim_{K\to \infty}S_K(g)||_p^p\stackrel{\text{definition of g}}=||g||_p^p\leq (||f_{n_1}||+1)^p
$$

Comment: how did you move the limit inside $(\Vert f_{n_1}\Vert+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k})^p$

Comment: It should be a finite sum until you take the limit. All you need is basic limit facts for that, like continuity of $x\mapsto x^p$ and additivity of the limit

Comment: how is that you applied monotone convergence to move the limit inside?

Comment: monotone convergence was used to move the limit $\lim_{K}||S_K(g)||_p^p=||\lim_{K}S_K(g)||_p^p$